# CoteJS creating multiple services does not work

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, cote

AM creating multiple services using [cote.js](http://cote.js.org/) and I have like 40 services each in its own file. So the problem is if I start two of them, They work without issue but if I start a third one or all of them, they don't work including the two that worked before, a screenshot of console output:

This is how it's supposed to be (when two services are launched)
[image: expected]

But this is what am getting (when more than two are launched):
[image: outputted]

`request journey begins` is the very first line of code in the very first middleware of the app

`sending...` is an output just before `requester.send` function is called

`recieved: null` is an output in the first line of code execution in the `requester.send` function callback, the `null` is the `error` argument of the callback.

My code is the usual/normal requester/responder from the site's documentation page only that one of the services is from the app which also has [express](https://expressjs.com/) `listen` function (ExpressJS app).

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

My requester:

```
const requester = new Requester({
    name: 'app-main',
    key: process.env.APP_NAME
}, {
    redis: {
        host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        port: process.env.REDIS_PORT
    }
} as any);

app.set('requester', requester);
```

Am basically using this requester throughout the routes of my application

My responder:

```
import {config} from 'dotenv';
import {basename, resolve} from 'path';
import {Responder} from 'cote';

import * as moment from 'moment';

import {ServiceCallback, ServiceRequest, LoggingParam} from '../helpers/types';
import logger from '../logger';

config({
    path: resolve(__dirname, '..', '.env')
});

const responder = new Responder({
    name: basename(__filename).substring(0, basename(__filename).indexOf('.service')),
    key: process.env.APP_NAME
}, {
    redis: {
        host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        port: Number(process.env.REDIS_PORT)
    }
} as any);

responder.on(basename(__filename).substring(basename(__filename).indexOf('.') + 1, basename(__filename).indexOf('.service')), (request: ServiceRequest, callback: ServiceCallback) => {
    const logParam: LoggingParam = {
        level: 'info',
        load: {
            route: {
                userAgent: request.userAgent,
                ip: request.ip,
                body: request.requestBody,
                name: 'test'
            },
            content: {
                message: 'Test function accessed'
            }
        }
    };

    logger(logParam);

    callback(null, {
        status: 200,
        body: `
            <h1>API is up</h1>
            <p>Server time is ${moment().utcOffset(3).toDate()}</p>
        `
    });
});
```

My routes declaration sample:

```
router.post('/settings', (request: Request, response: Response) => requestHandler(request, response, 'settings'));
```

Request handler function:

```
export function requestHandler(request: express.Request, response: express.Response, handle: string): void {
    const requester: Requester = request.app.get('requester');

    const requestObject: ServiceRequest = {
        type: handle,
        channel: request.body.channel,
        requestBody: request.body.data,
        user: request.body.user,
        userAgent: request.get('User-Agent'),
        ip: request.ip
    };

    requester.send(requestObject, (error: any, result: ServiceResponse) => {
        if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || !request.body.keyCombo) {
            response.status(result.status).send(result.body);

            return;
        }

        let dataToEncrypt = result.body;

        if (result.body.constructor === {}.constructor) {
            dataToEncrypt = JSON.stringify(result.body);
        }

        const credentials = request.body.keyCombo.split(';');

        const key = enc.Utf8.parse(credentials[0]);
        const iv = enc.Utf8.parse(credentials[1]);

        const toEncrypt = enc.Utf8.parse(dataToEncrypt);

        const encrypted = AES.encrypt(toEncrypt, key, { iv: iv }).toString();

        response.status(result.status).send(encrypted);
    });
}
```

If you need me to publish any more code please just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you did not solve this , I just ran into the same problem and you have to use keys

> Keys cote has another mechanism to create partitions called keys.
>   Since every component discovers and tries to communicate with every
>   other component on the horizon (this is called a "mesh network"), if
>   different services request and respond to different types of messages,
>   you will experience lost messages. In other words, if service A
>   responds to messages X and Y, and service B responds to messages Z and
>   T, you will lose half of the messages, because messages Z and T will
>   also end up at service A, but it won't know how to handle them. The
>   same is true for service B: messages X and Y will end up at it, but
>   service B won't know how to respond to them.

Comment: thanks, I will look at it, and yea, I actually did not solve this